# Does $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i(x) \sqrt{q_i(x)} =0 $ imply that $x$ is algebraic?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, combinatorial-number-theory

Let $p_i,q_i \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ and Let $P(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i(x) \sqrt{q_i(x)} $. Can we deduce that if $P(x) = 0$ then $x$ is an algebraic number?
For some simple examples I can see that it's true, like trivially if $P(x)$ is itself in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, or if $P_1(x) = \sqrt{q_1(x)}$ then $x$ satisfies $P_1(x)^2 = 0$ where $ P_1(x)^2 \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$. For $P_2(x) = \sqrt{q_1(x)} + \sqrt{q_2(x)} + p_3(x)$ also one can do the following
$$ \sqrt{q_1(x)} + \sqrt{q_2(x)} =- p_3(x) \\ q_1(x) + q_2(x) + 2\sqrt{q_1(x)q_2(x)} = p_3(x)^2 \\  2\sqrt{q_1(x)q_2(x)} = p_3(x)^2 - q_1(x) - q_2(x) \\ 4 \ q_1(x)q_2(x) = \big(p_3(x)^2 - q_1(x) - q_2(x)\big)^2 $$
And so again we can see that $x$ is algebraic. The same technique is applicable to $P_3(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{q_i(x)}$ with $n \leq 5$ by moving the radicals to different sides of the equation. But for example I don't have an idea for $P_4(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{q_i(x)}$ with $ n \geq 6$, the above technique for $P_2(x)$ and $P_3(x)$ does not seem to me to be applicable in this case: For $P_4(x)$ we might want to put $4$ radicals at on left side of the equation and the other $2$ at the right side. Then raising to the second power would produce $6$ radicals at left and $1$ at right, which counts for total of $7$ radicals, and that's more than the number of radicals we started with. For other partitionings of the radicals in the equation the problem still doesn't get solved with this approach; I see that's basically because $ { n \choose 2} \geq n $ for $n \geq 3$. And this is where I got stuck.

I would appreciate suggestions for proceeding and answers.

Comment: I think $\prod_{\epsilon\in \{\pm 1\}^n}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n{\epsilon_i p_i(X)\sqrt{q_i(X)}}\right)}$ is a rational polynomial function (it’s stable under the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(X,\sqrt{q_i(X)})/\mathbb{Q}(X)$). It also vanishes at $x$. QED.

Comment: @Mindlack I can't see what elements of this Galois group look like; could you please explain them a little bit?

Comment: @ThePhoenix I agree that among these $2^n+1$ polynomials, at least two of them would contain some same $\sqrt{ \Pi_{\alpha \in I} \ q_{\alpha}(x) }$ where $I$ is a subset of $ \{1,2,\dots, n\}$, so these two specific square-root expressions can be cancelled out. But we also can cancel out all the other square root expressions?

Comment: @Kooranifar: it’s a Kummer extension, basically an automorphism is determined by its values at the $\sqrt{q_i(X)}$, and they can each be $\pm \sqrt{q_i(X)}$. So we get an injective morphism from the Galois group into $\{\pm 1\}^n$.